# Is there a way to search with regex/symbols in XML searches

Tags: xquery

My data in xDB consist of values with / and regex. I tried using wildcards and other selection options but it doesn't seems to work, the only one that work is if I use the second one to search but it doesn't work with wildcards.

**#1**

```
    for $elem in /APP/TABLE/ROW where $elem/DATA contains text &apos;DL/B125.*&apos; using wildcards
    return $elem
```

**#2**

```
    for $elem in /APP/TABLE/ROW where $elem/DATA=&apos;DL/B125KT&apos;
    return $elem
```

Is there a way to search using wildcards where the values contains symbols/regex?

Comment: Which XQuery processor, which XQuery db is that??

Comment: XDK and for XQuery db, is it something like xhive or OpenText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the `matches()` function -

```
for $elem in /APP/TABLE/ROW where matches($elem/DATA, 'DL/B125.*')
    return $elem
```

or more concisely

```
/APP/TABLE/ROW[matches(DATA, 'DL/B125.*')]
```

(Do remember that not every query has to be a FLWOR expression)